IQ test puzzle with diagonal line of clocks
Please solve this for me.
Source: https://www.treningmozga.com/vi/iq/iq-test-33/iq-test-answers.php?noa=162341346213251643556123342213&chnu=115975&lstqu=30&qu=26


Hi Tuan where did you get this puzzle from?

The answer is

A (top left option)

As the rule is

For each clock, the small hand is where the large hand is on the clock to the right, and the large hand is where the small hand is on the clock to the left




Ah I came too late this was my logic too…

I'm with you that the large hand going to the small, but I don't see the small hand going to a place where the large hand has been before.. or maybe I'm misinterpreting something?

I thought it’s just that the small hand switches to the large hand going from left to right, if you look at the top back you just convert the large hand to the small hand and from the fourth figure forward just convert small to large

That will generate the first option

If this is the case the small hand just seems very random

Ahh gotcha now, didn't get the left-right/right-left explanation before. Nice job!

But it isn’t necessary to point that out…

@PDT changed how I've phrased it, is the new wording better/clearer?

No I understood I just don’t think it’s needed to deduce the answer. You are effectively saying the same thing twice.

Yes that’s much clearer!!

@PDT I think we we're saying the same thing, just I was saying it badly :P
